# If $(g'(x))^2 = g(x)$...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is if $(g'(x))^2 = g(x)$ for all real $x$ and $g(0) = 0$, $g(4) = 4$, then $g(1)$ equals...

The answer is 1/4.

I was thinking if you plugged in the numbers, then that would mean $g'(0) = 0$ and $g'(4) = +-2$, but I'm not sure how that will help me with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=y$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^{\frac 12}$

$\int y^{-\frac 12} dy = \int dx $

$2y^{\frac 12}=x+c$

$y= \left(\frac{x +c}{2}\right)^2$

the condition g(0)=0 lets you set c=0

Comment: The condition $g(4) = 4$ is also important, note that the constant function $g(x) = 0$ also solves the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

This yield a differential equation $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\pm \sqrt{y}$$ which can [separate variables](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSeparation_of_variables&ei=zOolVavtAofY8gX_-oCgCA&usg=AFQjCNGjITX9R-h6Y_HwqEvUYB5oHle7eg) $x$ and $y$.